# How to run php in High Sierra 10.13.14 using apachectl

Tags: php, macos, apache, macos-high-sierra

I have been trying to run PHP in my mac book for 2 days, But nothing seems to work. I followed many solutions on StackOverflow and on other sites nothing worked. I am using apachectl.

uname -a

```
Darwin MacBook-Pro-2.local 17.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.5.0: Mon Mar  5 22:24:32 PST 2018; root:xnu-4570.51.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

apachectl syntax check:

```
➜  ~ apachectl -t
Syntax OK
➜  ~
```

httpd configuration files:

```
➜  ~ locate httpd.conf
/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf.pre-update
/private/etc/apache2/original/httpd.conf
```

Contents of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf

```
https://pastebin.com/jMP6gDFR
```

Contents of /private/etc/apache2/original/httpd.conf

```
https://pastebin.com/vg5VABCP
```

EDIT: Anyone can help again now it stopped working again :(
Thank you!

Comment: NVM! It worked when I created a PHP file in `/Library/WebServer/Documents`.